# Installing led light

Tags: electrical

Old light fixture removed by painter so I don’t know how it was connected to junction box. Junction box has 2 sets of 3 wires , a total of 6 wires.  A Black, a white, and a bare copper in each set. How do I connect new led light fixture (that has one black, one white, one ground wire)  to old junction box wires?

The switch for the light has one black, one white and a ground screw that has no ground wire connected to it.

[image]

Comment: When you connected all blacks/ all whites, did you trip the breaker when you hit the switch? Theoretically, your light should have been permanently on.

Comment: This also raises the possibility that you killed the switch. Take it out with the power off and test for continuity with the multimeter.

Comment: ask the painter to give you the pictures of the wires before they were disconnected

Answer (score 1):

@Crip659 is likely right (99.5% probability) - plus 1 to him.
Tool to find which is power. Please shut off the breaker once you figure out which is hot.

[image: Amazon]

Artist rendition of the wiring :)
[image]
Notice white wire is used as hot feeder to the switch, the black wire as the switch leg, which is why it is called a switch loop. The white wire, now power, should be marked with red tape so nobody mistakes it for neutral. The white wire from the power input wire is neutral for the light. (Ground wire is not shown.

Comment: Seems like lots of leftover wires after looking at diagram.  I have a multi meter

Comment: No extra wires. Black from power wire to White (red tape) from switch loop. White from power wire to white from light fixture.  Black from switch loop to black from fixture. All copper and green wires are tied together for grounding.  Should be the exact number of wires in the box and fixture. (The switch in the diagram is for reference only. Use you meter to measure the two black wires to ground to see which is hot (mark it), turn off breaker, and go from there. If there are more wires in the box, you have a power out also and need to figure that out.